# Updating column in Table A with data from a column in Table B where a certain condition from Table A is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to copy all the values from a single column in one table, using the values from the column in to another table.

This provides me the data I need to update

```
SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.Tablewheredatais
INNER JOIN DB.dbo.TableIneedtoupdate ON DB.dbo.Tablewheredatais.FKfromTableIneedtoupdate = DB.dbo.TableIneedtoupdate.PK
WHERE ColumnfromTableIneedtoupdate ='stringvalue'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I think you forgot to ask a question. If you did it is not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start. Also see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This logic will join your tables on the id and then update a column based on a conditional value present in the target table (demo: http://rextester.com/SJU58235)

```
UPDATE TableIneedtoupdate SET
TableIneedtoupdate.targetColumn = Tablewheredatais.sourceColumn
FROM Tablewheredatais
INNER JOIN TableIneedtoupdate
ON TableIneedtoupdate.fkid = Tablewheredatais.id 
WHERE TableIneedtoupdate.data2 ='stringValue'
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks :). You made me realize I wasn't addressing the tables in the right order when running the update statement.